# making a quick view modal for your shopping cart

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, shopping-cart

I'm making a shopping cart with asp.net core mvc and jquery. I get items into a foreach loop to display all items in a grid and other information into @Html.Hidden("Description", (object)item.Description). I created a quick view button to popup for more details of the product. The challenge I have is that when I click on the quick view, I want to be able to view details of the selected product. I have been able to get the image of the product, when any of the items quick view is clicked using this code:

```
var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').find('img:first');
var slectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');
```

Apart from the image, I've been having difficulty getting other properties, such as price, description, alternate image etc, which are all in hidden fields. Please check my code below:

```
<div class="row isotope-grid">
        @if (ViewBag.AllProducts != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.AllProducts)
            {
                var photoPath4 = "~/images/" + (@item.PicPathMain ?? "placehold.jpg");

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src=@photoPath4 id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT" asp-append-version="true" />

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", new { ID = item.ID })" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    @item.Name
                                </a>

                                @Html.Hidden("Image1", (object)item.PicPathMain)
                                @Html.Hidden("Image2", (object)item.PicPathLeft)
                                @Html.Hidden("Image3", (object)item.PicPathRight)
                                @Html.Hidden("Description", (object)item.Description)
                                @Html.Hidden("Price", (object)item.Price)
                                @Html.Hidden("Size", (object)item.Size)
                                @Html.Hidden("ProdName", (object)item.Name)
                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    N @item.Price
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }


    </div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$('.js-show-modal1').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');
    //Get Product Image
    var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').find('img:first');
    var slectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');
    $('#imgPic1').attr('src', slectedImageUrl);
    
    //Get Product Name
    var productName = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').find('input[name="ProdName"]');
    var selectedName = productName.attr('value');
    $('.mtext-105').html(selectedName);
});
```

Update:
Please check below the rendered html of the grid.

```
<div class="row isotope-grid" style="position: relative; height: 890px;">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="/images/476cd102-95e4-406e-b4b1-bc24ff56c08a_73_AFRO1_L.jpg?v=clql7fMRxRm6EOgTPdinW74B9xv6lFre36t5VFvywJk" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/1" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    AFRO KINKY
                                </a>

                                <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="476cd102-95e4-406e-b4b1-bc24ff56c08a_73_AFRO1_L.jpg">
                                <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="17a7303e-6d2f-44d7-bc2c-7516a04311c4_DSS-620-X-600-1.jpg.pagespeed.ce.4HxAdKZ6OR.jpg">
                                <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="f3914b31-337b-4a16-bb21-9e49e0f8c343_ed1.jpg">
                                <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="ROSA">
                                <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="15000.00">
                                <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="14">
                                <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="AFRO KINKY">
                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    N 15000.00
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0px;">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="/images/5d7e96c5-2c01-4f3f-9cfa-09f327aab817_model-model-remy-dream-weaver-dream-weaver-yaky-10.jpg?v=g2USmv3vBYuLBjEOKra5zavJnxo_4CoMlz8LtDl8hLQ" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/2" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    LACE WIG
                                </a>

                                <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="5d7e96c5-2c01-4f3f-9cfa-09f327aab817_model-model-remy-dream-weaver-dream-weaver-yaky-10.jpg">
                                <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
                                <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="16000.00">
                                <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
                                <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="LACE WIG">
                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    N 16000.00
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 445px;">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="/images/ed347c52-e1ab-4059-9207-742c04f6d242_KZ6OR.jpg?v=lLlRsUR3vXeV76vghx52VY8HicpXGNKpVTSFurOtleM" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/3" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    LACE WIG
                                </a>

                                <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="ed347c52-e1ab-4059-9207-742c04f6d242_KZ6OR.jpg">
                                <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
                                <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="22500.00">
                                <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
                                <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="LACE WIG">
                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    N 22500.00
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 445px;">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="/images/e72f6dd5-a2f1-448f-abf6-a3ed08547bb7_ed6.jpg?v=wnPvcpEnY7CmfOZbwzVKf2sfZqeGOUdx0znVbL9RHsU" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/4" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    RED ROSES
                                </a>

                                <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="e72f6dd5-a2f1-448f-abf6-a3ed08547bb7_ed6.jpg">
                                <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
                                <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="17000.00">
                                <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
                                <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="RED ROSES">
                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    N 17000.00
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Please also include the HTML that is rendered for the grid. You will get more answers from people who can help you with the JS/jQuery issue but may not know how ASP.Net MVC Core renders `@Html.Hidden()`.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminRay, please check the update of the post for the rendered Html of the grid. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. Note that you haven't added your HTML for the modal, so the class names to which the results are written to are just examples and have to be adjusted by you. Also note that your HTML isn't valid because you use duplicate ids while ids have to be unique. There might be no need to use ids like Image1, Image2 and so on as all of the inputs also have a name attribute with the same value.

```js
$('.js-show-modal1').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');

  var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').find('img:first');
  var selectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');
  $('#imgPic1').attr('src', selectedImageUrl);

  var productName = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="ProdName"]');
  var selectedName = productName.attr('value');
  $('.mtext-105').html(selectedName);

  var productPrice = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="Price"]');
  var selectedPrice = productPrice.attr('value');
  $('.mtext-106').html(selectedPrice);
  
  var productDescription = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="Description"]');
  var selectedDescription = productDescription.attr('value');
  $('.mtext-107').html(selectedDescription);

  var productSize = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="Size"]');
  var selectedSize = productSize.attr('value');
  $('.mtext-107').html(selectedSize);

  var selectedImage2 = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="Image2"]');
  var selectedImage2Url = selectedImage2.attr('value');
  $('#imgPic2').attr('src', selectedImage2Url);

  var selectedImage3 = $(this).parent('.hov-img0').next(".block2-txt").find('input[name="Image3"]');
  var selectedImage3Url = selectedImage3.attr('value');
  $('#imgPic3').attr('src', selectedImage3Url);
  
   console.log("Product Name: " + selectedName);
   console.log("Product Image: " + selectedImageUrl);
   console.log("Product Price: " + selectedPrice);
   console.log("Product Size: " + selectedSize);
   console.log("Product Description: " + selectedDescription);
   console.log("Product Image 2: " + selectedImage2Url);
   console.log("Product Image 3: " + selectedImage3Url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row isotope-grid" style="position: relative; height: 890px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
        <img src="/images/476cd102-95e4-406e-b4b1-bc24ff56c08a_73_AFRO1_L.jpg?v=clql7fMRxRm6EOgTPdinW74B9xv6lFre36t5VFvywJk" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
          Quick View
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
          <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/1" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
            AFRO KINKY
          </a>

          <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="476cd102-95e4-406e-b4b1-bc24ff56c08a_73_AFRO1_L.jpg">
          <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="17a7303e-6d2f-44d7-bc2c-7516a04311c4_DSS-620-X-600-1.jpg.pagespeed.ce.4HxAdKZ6OR.jpg">
          <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="f3914b31-337b-4a16-bb21-9e49e0f8c343_ed1.jpg">
          <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="ROSA">
          <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="15000.00">
          <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="14">
          <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="AFRO KINKY">
          <span class="stext-105 cl3">
            N 15000.00
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
            <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
            <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0px;">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
        <img src="/images/5d7e96c5-2c01-4f3f-9cfa-09f327aab817_model-model-remy-dream-weaver-dream-weaver-yaky-10.jpg?v=g2USmv3vBYuLBjEOKra5zavJnxo_4CoMlz8LtDl8hLQ" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
          Quick View
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
          <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/2" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
            LACE WIG
          </a>

          <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="5d7e96c5-2c01-4f3f-9cfa-09f327aab817_model-model-remy-dream-weaver-dream-weaver-yaky-10.jpg">
          <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
          <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="16000.00">
          <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
          <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="LACE WIG">
          <span class="stext-105 cl3">
            N 16000.00
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
            <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
            <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 445px;">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
        <img src="/images/ed347c52-e1ab-4059-9207-742c04f6d242_KZ6OR.jpg?v=lLlRsUR3vXeV76vghx52VY8HicpXGNKpVTSFurOtleM" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
          Quick View
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
          <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/3" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
            LACE WIG
          </a>

          <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="ed347c52-e1ab-4059-9207-742c04f6d242_KZ6OR.jpg">
          <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
          <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="22500.00">
          <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
          <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="LACE WIG">
          <span class="stext-105 cl3">
            N 22500.00
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
            <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
            <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 445px;">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
        <img src="/images/e72f6dd5-a2f1-448f-abf6-a3ed08547bb7_ed6.jpg?v=wnPvcpEnY7CmfOZbwzVKf2sfZqeGOUdx0znVbL9RHsU" id="imgPix2" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
          Quick View
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
          <a href="/Home/ProductDetail/4" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
            RED ROSES
          </a>

          <input id="Image1" name="Image1" type="hidden" value="e72f6dd5-a2f1-448f-abf6-a3ed08547bb7_ed6.jpg">
          <input id="Image2" name="Image2" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Image3" name="Image3" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" value="HAIR DOM">
          <input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" value="17000.00">
          <input id="Size" name="Size" type="hidden" value="15">
          <input id="ProdName" name="ProdName" type="hidden" value="RED ROSES">
          <span class="stext-105 cl3">
            N 17000.00
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
            <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
            <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthias_h, you have saved the day, it never occurred to me to look at it this way at all. Thanks again

Comment: @AyodeleTimothy Glad that I was able to help :)